# How to make Fractional Scaling work on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display-resolution, wayland

I use a QHD Monitor and would like to use 125% or 150% scaling. Im changing the Settings in the 'Display' Options. If I do this on Xorg, i get stutters, lags and some bugs with external monitors. If I am on Wayland everything is blurry. So for now I am just using 100% scaling but everything is quite small. Is there some way to make it work, e.g. using the CLI? Im on a X1 Carbon if that helps.